# MPMoviePlayerController endPlaybackTime problem

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am having an issue with the endPlaybackTime.  I am trying to auto start and stop the video mid-way through the 30 second video

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self urlForVideo:video]];
player.view.frame = [self getVideoCGRect:self.interfaceOrientation];
player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

//-------------------------
player.currentPlaybackTime = 10.0;
player.endPlaybackTime = 18.35;
//---------------------
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

But, this doesn't seem to want to stop in the correct place.  It just plays to the end and stops.  Any idea why not?

Answer (score 0):

endPlaybackTime property is not available for streaming video. Hope you're not trying to stop streaming video. Also it's 30 seconds or 30 minutes in length?

Comment: It's not streaming. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you get any notification fired for movie player at the end of endPlaybackTime?